# how to push all value of an array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

For this kind of array:

```
 let combinazioniMat = [
     ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6"],
     ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6"],
     ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person6", "Person5"],
    ]
```

I want for each array to add each of the element of another array:

```
let mediciPom = ["Person1", "Person4"]
```

I tried to do like this, but it doesn't work...

```
let combinazioniTemp =[]

for (let combN=0; combN<combinazioniMat.length;combN++){
for (let med of mediciPom){
combinazioniMat[combN].push(med);
combinazioniTemp.push(combinazioniMat[combN]);
combinazioniMat[combN].pop()
}}
```

THIS IS THE RESULT I WANT TO OBTAIN (UPDATED):

```
    [
      ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6", "Person1" ],
      ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6", "Person4" ],
      ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6", "Person1" ], 
      ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6", "Person4" ], 
      ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person6", "Person5", "Person1" ],
      ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person6", "Person5", "Person4" ],
   ]
```

Moreover, I need the same function, but pushing the value only if not already present in the array
To obtain this:

```
[
["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6", "Person4" ],
["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person6", "Person5", "Person4" ],
]
```

(Person1 will not be pushed because already present, and Person4 will be pushed only in the array in which it isn't)

Thanks and sorry if I was not clear before...

Comment: what is this all for?

Comment: `const targetArr = combinazioniMat.map(x => [...x, ...mediciPom]);` <--- please try this and share your feedback. This will add all elements of `mediciPom` into each array within `combinazioniMat`.

Comment: And what if I want this insert the value only if is not already present in the array?

Comment: @Damiano your question contradicts that --- your desired output has dupicate values

Comment: I know... but I realized that i need both the output...

Comment: @jsN00b It doesn't work. It add both the value at the end. I need one value. And repeating with each value...

Comment: @Damiano well can you update your question and explain what you want? just add an example output for the additional requirement

Comment: If you want to ensure that the desired/target array does not have duplicates (like `"Person1"` occurs only once, not twice), this should work: `const targetArr = combinazioniMat.map(x => [...x.filter(y => !mediciPom.includes(y)), ...mediciPom]);`

Comment: @Damiano see my updated answer if it is what you want

Comment: @skara9 I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that edit changes your question completely, so I'm posting a new answer.

So for the first part I'm assuming you want to replicate each subarray with a different value from `mediciPom` each time.

For that you can make use of the [`<Array>.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) function:

```js
combinazioniMat.flatMap(arr => mediciPom.map(e => arr.concat(e)));
```

---

For the second part, you can just falsify the value when the element already exists, and then run the output array through a simple truth filter.

```js
combinazioniMat.flatMap(arr => mediciPom.map(e => !arr.includes(e) && arr.concat(e))).filter(n=>n);
```

---

Full Example: `withDuplicates` is the first method, `withoutDuplicates` is the second:

```js
let combinazioniMat = [
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person6", "Person5"],
]

let mediciPom = ['Person1', 'Person4'];

let withDuplicates = combinazioniMat.flatMap(arr => mediciPom.map(e => arr.concat(e)));
let withoutDuplicates = combinazioniMat.flatMap(arr => mediciPom.map(e => !arr.includes(e) && arr.concat(e))).filter(n=>n);

console.log('FIRST', withDuplicates)
console.log('SECOND', withoutDuplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Find the remainder of the array index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder), and use that to grab the element from the `mediciPom` array.

```js
const combinazioniMat=[["Person1","Person2","Person3","Person4","Person6"],["Person1","Person2","Person3","Person5","Person6"],["Person1","Person2","Person3","Person6","Person5"],["Person1","Person2","Person4","Person5","Person6"],["Person1","Person2","Person4","Person6","Person5"],["Person1","Person2","Person5","Person3","Person6"],["Person1","Person2","Person5","Person4","Person6"],["Person1","Person2","Person5","Person6","Person4"],["Person1","Person2","Person4","Person3","Person6"]];
const mediciPom = ['Person1', 'Person2'];

for (let i = 0; i < combinazioniMat.length; i++)  {
  const mp = mediciPom[i % 2];
  combinazioniMat[i].push(mp);
}

console.log(combinazioniMat);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It add alternately one value, I need to add each value for each array... for example  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6", "Person1"],
     ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6", "Person2"],

Comment: This is exactly what you asked for. How is what you need any different from my answer? I don't understand. @Damiano

Comment: Sorry, I updated the sample because I realize it wasn't clear...

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```js
let combinazioniMat = [
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person6", "Person5"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person4", "Person5", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person4", "Person6", "Person5"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person5", "Person3", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person5", "Person4", "Person6"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person5", "Person6", "Person4"],
  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person4", "Person3", "Person6"],
];

let mediciPom = ["Person1", "Person2"];

let combinazioniTemp = combinazioniMat.map((el, index) => [
  ...el,
  mediciPom[index % 2],
]);

console.log(combinazioniTemp);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It add alternately one value, I need to add each value for each array... for example  ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person6", "Person1"],
     ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person5", "Person6", "Person2"],

Comment: this will work:

let combinazioniTemp = combinazioniMat.map((el, index) => [
  ...el,
  mediciPom[index],
]);

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I hope I cleared in the updated question. The code you wrote doesn't works.